Blender FBX Importer potentially ignoring (legacy) FBX mesh instances?
Blender 3.6. I do not know much about the technical side of the FBX format, so bear with me.
I am working with some legacy FBX files used internally in a videogame engine. These FBX files can contain information about objects that share the geometry data with a different object, but have their own unique transforms - instances in other words. In ASCII FBX they are defined as
GenericNode: "StaticMeshActor_2TFTD", "GenericNode" {
Version: 100
Properties60:  {
    Property: "instanceUVTranslate", "Vector3D", "",0.62548828125,-0.00390625,0
    Property: "instanceUVScale", "Vector3D", "",0.125,1,0
    Property: "instanceGeometry", "KString", "", "StaticMeshActor_3TFTD"
    Property: "instanceTransform", "matrix4x4", "",1,0,-1.22460635382238e-016,-546.0126953125,-0,1,-0,-10.015625,-1.22460635382238e-016
     ,-0,-1,310.858337402344,0,0,0,1
    Property: "renderStats", "KString", "", ",disableCastShadows,disableVisibleInFG,disableCastGI,disableVisibleInFG,disablePrimaryVisibility,disableVisibleInRefractions,disableVisibleInReflections,disableVisibleInFG,disableCastOcclusion"
     
} 

In this case  GenericNode: "StaticMeshActor_2TFTD" is the name of the object, while Property: "instanceGeometry", ... "StaticMeshActor_3TFTD" is the name of the object the geometry of which is being used.
So, question number one is - is this a native FBX feature or is this a custom addition made by the game developers, based on the fact that these files were meant for internal use? From what I gather, as long as you use the proper FBX syntax you can define your own custom data properties inside the ASCII FBX and by extension its binary version and it will not affect the conversion process between the two. It being called a GenericNode might hint at that, I suppose.
The issue that I am facing currently is that both 3ds Max and Blender simply ignore these instanced objects - they do not load them at all, even as duplicate geometry, they simply skip them while loading everything else. This is true for both the native Blender FBX importer and the Better FBX importer addon which uses FBX SDK.
In case this is in fact part of the official FBX format:
Is this just a limitation of the current FBX importer and or an issue caused by the fact that this is an outdated way of defining instances? Is there a fix or a workaround available?
In any other case:
Is there an FBX importer for Blender which does not rely on FBX SDK and supports ASCII format? So that I could at least try and add the support for this potentially custom instancing.
I guess I might also just write a script which would copy the geometry data from the object they`re referencing into the instance object node, instead of trying to rewrite the importer.
Any help is appreciated.

This is the 3.6 Blender manual section for the FBX importer/exporter. It does say that the importer lacks a lot of the export functions. It looks as if there's a more comprehensive (commercial) importer/exporter addon here.

@JohnEason
I have tried the addon you linked before posting, the behaviour is identical - as in, it ignores these special instances, which leads me to believe that this is in fact a custom FBX addition unsupported by normal importers.

Worth a try. In that case you'll have to write your own importer if you can find the specifications. There are no Blender developers here so you're on your own I'm afraid.
